# Comparing two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, similarity

I want to compare a user profile with another user profile based on education, experiences, skills, and country. If education is similar, the score will be 20, else it will be 0. And `total_score` will be the sum of the scores. I can then sort profiles similar to that of a given user based on the total score. Can anyone help me on how I can achieve this?

I don't know how to compare two users or two things from the same table, and I don't know where to put my code in: the profile model, helper, or what.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your User model.

```
def total_score
  education+skills+country #modify to determine score, idk how you plan to determine this
end
```

When trying to sort:

```
User.all.sort_by{|a| a.total_score} #returns a list of users sorted by total score.
```

**EDIT**

I think you mean this:

```
def total_score
  score=0
  if education=="First School"
     score+=10
  elsif education=="Second School"
     score+=5
  end

  if skill=="Skill 1"
     score+=10
  elsif education=="Skill 2"
     score+=5
  end

  if country=="Country 1"
     score+=10
  elsif country=="Country 2"
     score+=5
  end
end
```

Comment: but how can i compare two user this is the part that i don't know how can i achieve it  de total_score weight= 0  weight += 20 if self.educations == "what"

Comment: but how can i do it dynamically comparing each user based on this to a given user

Comment: User.find(1).total_score > User.find(2).total_score

Comment: You could also implement the [Comparable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html) and [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)in User.rb